# How can I get all the methods which have to implement of an interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin which will create one class with implement interface.The interface may have inherited methods.
I also want to implement all the methods including inherited one at the time of creation of  the class.Not after the class created and then by using eclipse quick fix--add unimplemented methods.
Is there any way to get list of all methods including inherited ones of an interface?

Comment: Eclipse helps you with that as soon as you implement an interface.

Comment: Unless you are developing a plug-in your question is already been answered by the other users.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse then eclipse will help you to implement all the required  methods which are necessary else you have to see  which non implemented  method interface has,which you need to implement

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse JAVA editor, you should see an `yellow bulb icon with red cross sign`(red cross sign is displayed when there are some unimplemented interface methods in the class) in front of the class declaration line. `Right click -> quick fix and select the option add unimplemented methods`. Eclipse will add stub of all your interface `X` methods in `ClassA` body. If there is `no red cross sign` and your class is getting compiled, it mean, there is no unimplemented method from the class.

Alternative, you can press `ctrl+1` on `class A implements X{}` line and select the `add unimplemented methods` option from the menu opened.

**Please Note:** Hope you have turned on the auto build in Eclipse. If not, please force build to see the compilation error first(red cross sign) in class file open through Java Editor.

Answer (score 0):

simply when you implemented X in class A then all method which is abstract and not concrete show as a n option when you press Eclipse help short key ctrl+spacebar

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example is what you want.

```
package com.interfaces;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class TestImplement  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Class<?> c = MyInterface.class;     
        Method[] m = c.getMethods();
        for (int i=0; i<m.length ; i++){
            System.out.println(m[i].toString());
        }       
    }
}

interface MyInterface extends Runnable{
    public void test(); 

}
```